# Why is this a never ending loop?

Tags: javascript

I want this to run then gameOnAgain to run, then back again... But I keep gettng an endless loop

The game is supposed to allow the first player to click on a div and then place a character inside then go on to the next player. But after 2 turns in each, the game creates an endless loop that crashed my browser

```
function gameOn() {
    count++;
    winner();
    if (playerOneTurn === true) {
        $("#top1").on("click", function () {
            $("#top1").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell1 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
        $("#top2").on("click", function () {
            $("#top2").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell2 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
        $("#top3").on("click", function () {
            $("#top3").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell3 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
        $("#middle1").on("click", function () {
            $("#middle1").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell4 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
        $("#middle2").on("click", function () {
            $("#middle2").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell5 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
        $("#middle3").on("click", function () {
            $("#middle3").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell6 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
        $("#bottom1").on("click", function () {
            $("#bottom1").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell8 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
        $("#bottom2").on("click", function () {
            $("#bottom2").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell8 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
        $("#bottom3").on("click", function () {
            $("#bottom3").html(`<h2>${symbolp1}</h2>`);
            cell9 = true;
            playerTwoTurn = true;
            playerOneTurn = false;
            gameOnAgain();
        })
    } }

function gameOnAgain() {
    winner();
    if (playerTwoTurn === true) {
        $("#top1").on("click", function () {
            $("#top1").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);

            cell1 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
        $("#top2").on("click", function () {
            $("#top2").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);

            cell2 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
        $("#top3").on("click", function () {
            $("#top3").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);

            cell3 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
        $("#middle1").on("click", function () {
            $("#middle1").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);

            cell4 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
        $("#middle2").on("click", function () {
            $("#middle2").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);

            cell5 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
        $("#middle3").on("click", function () {
            $("#middle3").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);

            cell6 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
        $("#bottom1").on("click", function () {
            $("#bottom1").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);
            cell7 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
        $("#bottom2").on("click", function () {
            $("#bottom2").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);
            cell8 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
        $("#bottom3").on("click", function () {
            $("#bottom3").html(`<h2>${symbolp2}</h2>`);
            cell9 = false;
            playerOneTurn = true;
            playerTwoTurn = false;
            gameOn();
        })
    } }
```

Comment: What is does `winner()` do?

Comment: this code is awfully redundant. Stop thingking in absolutes like IDs (this exact node/cell, this particular players turn, ...), try to think in terms of groups/types, like a list of cells or rows or cols, a list of players, ... In your case there are two players; every odd turn is playerOnes (1,3,5,...) playerTwo on ever even turn (2,4,6,...).  Check this example out *(I guess, that's what you're building)* https://jsfiddle.net/pg6xpyjo/ Doesn't mean that that's the correct/only way to go, but you can definitely learn from that code.

Answer (score 1):

It would helped if you placed all your code in a JSBin and shared the link.

If the goal of the game is to take as many turns needed to complete the game, you could wrap the function in $(document).ready(function() { ... }), maintain state via an object and then decide when the game is over.

```
var Game = { 
   current_player: PLAYER_ID, 
            moves: [ { PLAYER_ID: CELL_ID } ]
}
```

In the above, current_player would be an integer, 1 or 2.  Moves is an array of past moves stored as hashes, with the player id as the key and cell as the value, i.e. { 1: 2 }.

You'd change your html from this:

```
<div id="top1"></div>
```

To something like:

```
<div class="game-cell" data-cell-id="1"></div>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
$('div.game-cell').click(function() {

  // Grab the current player from out 'game' object
  var player = game.current_player;

  // Associate the player with their symbol
  var symbol = "PLAYER_SYMBOL"; 

  // 'this' references the specific div.game-cell that was clicked
  $(this).html(`<h2>${symbol}</h2>`);

  // Grab the cell id from the data attribute
  var cell = $(this).data("cell-id");

  // Create an object for the move with the 'player' as the key, and 'cell' as the value
  var move =  { player : cell };

  // Store the move in the game object's moves array
  game.moves.push(move);

  // Update the current player value for the next player's turn
  game.current_player == 1 ? game.current_player = 2 : game.current_player = 1; 
})
```

You can then use your custom logic to determine when the game is over from the game object.

Also, this is a lot to take in, if it doesn't make sense at first - keep reading and asking questions. Just remember to try and keep your code DRY (not repeated) as it well benefit you as your codebase grows.